# How do I pipe comm outputs to a file?

Tags: unix

I've used the comm command to compare two files, but I'm unable to pipe it to a third file:

```
comm file1 file2 > file3 

comm: file 1 is not in sorted order
comm: file 2 is not in sorted order
```

How do I do this? **The files are sorted already.**

(comm file1 file2 works and prints it out)

sample input:
file1:

```
21
24
31
36
40
87
105
134
...
```

file2:

```
10
21
31
36
40
40
87
103
...
```

comm file1 file2: works

```
comm file1 file2 > file3 

comm: file 1 is not in sorted order
comm: file 2 is not in sorted order
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input that generates these messages?

Comment: What does `comm -3 file1 file2` show on stdout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've sorted numerically; `comm` works on lexically sorted files.

For instance, in `file2`, the line 103 is dramatically out of order with the lines 21..87.  Your files must be '*plain `sort` sorted*'.

If you've got `bash` (4.x), you can use process substitution:

```
comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

This runs the two commands and ensures that the `comm` process gets to read their standard output as if they were files.

Failing that:

```
(
sort -o file1 file1 &
sort -o file2 file2 &
wait
comm file1 file2
)
```

This uses parallelism to get the file sorted at the same time.  The sub-shell (in `( ... )`) ensures that you don't end up waiting for other background processes to finish.

Answer (score 3):

Your sample data is **NOT** sorted lexicographically (like in a dictionary), which is what commands like `comm` and `sort` (without the `-n` option) expect, where for example 100 should be before 20.

Are you sure that you aren't simply not noticing the error message when you don't redirect the output, since the error would be intermixed with the output lines on the terminal?

Comment: +1: I suspect this is the right answer (and you posted it while I ws typing mine).

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort the files first with the `sort` program.

Comment: Then use comm's `--nocheck-order` switch, although I'd try to find out why `comm` thinks they are not.

Comment: Here's why the error occurs with proofs:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/573503/334294

Comment: Note that this answer was written before the question was edited to add the claim that the files were already sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
sort -o file1 file1
sort -o file2 file2
comm file1 file2 > file3
```

Comment: @user794479 : why does your question explicitly mentions : comm: file 1 is not in sorted order comm: file 2 is not in sorted order

Comment: that's the output if I try to > file3

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the same results as you, but perhaps your version of `comm` is complaining that the files are not sorted lexically. Using the input you provided (the `...` makes it interesting, I know it's not a part of your actual files.)

```
$ comm file[12]
        10
                21
24
                31
                36
                40
        40
                87
        103
        ...
105
134
...
```

I was surprised that `...` wasn't in the third column, so I tried:

```
$ comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
                ...
        10
        103
105
134
                21
24
                31
                36
                40
        40
                87
```

That's better, but 105 > 24, right?

```
$ comm <(sort -n file1) <(sort -n file2)
                ...
        10
                21
24
                31
                36
                40
        40
                87
        103
105
134
```

I think those were the results you are looking for. The two `40`s are also interesting. If you want to eliminate these:

```
$ comm <(sort -nu file1) <(sort -nu file2)
                ...
        10
                21
24
                31
                36
                40
                87
        103
105
134
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, where `comm` was complaining even though I had run `sort`. The problem was that I was running Cygwin, and `sort` pointed to some MSDOS version (I guess). By using the specific path (C:\Cygwin\bin\sort in my case), it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I had sorted files but was getting the same error with

`comm -23 16-unique.log 23-unique.log > 16-only.log`

but I figured the redirection wasn't working properly so I tried

`(comm -23 16-unique.log 23-unique.log ) > 16-only.log`

but using sort to ensure the inputs where sorted was the business.

`comm -23 <(sort 16-unique.log) <( sort 23-unique.log)  > 16-only.log`

[As an side the -23 switch means that only the unique rows in the first file will be in the output] also [man comm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm)