# How do I find intersections between two git commits?

Tags: git

Namely, I am interested in finding files that were modified in both commits (or in two diffs if that is easier).  Excuse me if it's simple, but I am still pretty new to git.

Comment: Why do you need this? Maybe there is a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: We are interested in finding changes that may have been lost in a large commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

After inputs from @PaulHicks ( `git diff` instead of `git diff-tree` ...thanks Paul) and to circumvent the error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199975/how-do-i--comm-outputs-to-a-file) i.e `| sort` here's my updated answer:

```
comm -12 <(git diff --no-commit-id --name-only -r 3fe29472016343 | sort) <(git diff --no-commit-id --name-only -r 9fd796b1998bb7d5 | sort)
```

**Old Answer**
I dont believe there is a command out of the box to do what you want to achieve. However, If you are on *nix platforms you can try this:

```
comm -12  <(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r COMMIT1SHA1key) <(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r COMMIT2SHA1key)
```

unfortunately I am typing from windows box :( ..hence cannot check this right away (I have to go home and try)

My idea here is git diff-tree will produce a list of files like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424142/405117).

and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696111/405117) shows how this comm -12 works on `ls`.

Weaving both may work is my guess

Comment: I really just came across this on Stack Overflow...see those links in my answer

Comment: @PaulHicks thanks for letting me know...I unfortunately cannot check this right now as I am on a windows machine...I will go home and try it out

Comment: `<(...)` is a bash-ism: run the parenthesized command with its stdout going to a pipe, replace the `<(...)` part with a `/dev/fd/` ref to the pipe descriptor.  It's a handy trick for avoiding temporary files.

Comment: Note that `git diff-tree` with one commit-ID implicitly compares the tree with the commit's parent(s), and behaves differently (produces a combined diff) for a merge commit.

Comment: No I wasn't asking anything.  I just tried the syntax from the answer and I got no output for a commit that modified one file; the git diff approach from my answer give me the file that was changed.  It's probably just a minor syntax thing.

Comment: Ah yes, the SHA-1 I used was a merge.  diff-tree works fine for other SHA-1s.  The diff approach works in all cases though, which is handy.  I guess it depends on what you want from the command.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of files changed in a single commit using `git diff --name-only sha1^ sha1`.  So you could do this in a script which takes two commit SHA-1s as parameters:

```
git diff --name-only $1^ $1 | sort > file1
git diff --name-only $2^ $2 | sort > file2
comm -12 file1 file2
rm file1 file2
```

Or if you're using bash on linux/unix, you can use the nifty trick from @Vikram's answer to avoid the temporary files:

```
comm -12 < (git diff --name-only $1^ $1) < (git diff --name-only $2^ $2)
```